# Tikz, nodes in a tree become not fitted.

Tags: tikz-trees, fit

I want to draw 4 trees and I want to have some nodes in each of them fitted like in the first picture. But what is coming out is in the second picture. What is wrong with the code? Thanks in advance!!

[image]
[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,backgrounds,fit,shapes,decorations.pathreplacing}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[level distance=8.5mm,
level 1/.style={sibling distance=25mm},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=17mm},
level 3/.style={sibling distance=12mm},
level 4/.style={sibling distance=7mm},every fit/.style=    {rectangle,draw,inner sep=3.5pt}]

\node {+}
child {node {*}
    child {node{2}}
    child {node{$\pi$}}}
child {node {---}
    child {node {+}
        child {node {$x$}}
        child {node {3}}}
    child {node(/){/}
        child {node (y){y}}
        child {node (+){+}
            child {node (5){5}}
            child {node (1){1}}
}}};

\node [draw=green,fit=(/) (y) (+) (5) (1) ] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\hskip 10pt 
\begin{tikzpicture}
[level distance=11mm,
level 1/.style={sibling distance=25mm},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=17mm},
level 3/.style={sibling distance=12mm}, fit/.style={rectangle,draw=red,inner sep=3.5pt}]

\node (1){*}
child {node(*){*}
    child {node(a){$a$}}
    child {node(3){3}}}
child {node {+}
    child {node{3}}
    child {node {+}
            child {node {y}}
            child {node {12}}}
};
\node[fit={(a) (3) (*) (1)}]{};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[level distance=11mm,
level 1/.style={sibling distance=25mm},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=17mm},
level 3/.style={sibling distance=12mm}, fit/.style={rectangle,draw,inner sep=3.5pt}]
\node {+}
child {node {*}
    child {node{2}}
    child {node{$\pi$}}}
child {node {---}
    child {node {+}
        child {node {$x$}}
        child {node {3}}}
    child {node(*){*}
        child {node (a){$a$}}
        child {node (3){3}}
}};

\node [draw=red, fit={(*) ($a$) (3)}] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\hskip 10pt 
\begin{tikzpicture}
[level distance=11mm,
level 1/.style={sibling distance=25mm},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=17mm},
level 3/.style={sibling distance=12mm}, fit/.style={rectangle,draw,inner sep=3.5pt}]

\node {*}
child {node(/){/}
            child {node (y){y}}
            child {node (+){+}
                child {node (5){5}}
                child {node (1){1}}
}}
child {node {+}
    child {node{3}}
    child {node {+}
            child {node {y}}
            child {node {12}}}
};

\node [fit=(/) (y) (+) (5) (1),draw=green ]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for the record, here's a solution using the powerful [`forest`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest) package which I strongly suggest for trees; notice that, besides the economy in the code, the fitting is done in a very simply way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{73,137,132}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{150,177,192}

\forestset{
mytree/.style={
  baseline,
  for tree={
    parent anchor=south,
    s sep=15pt,
    content format={\ensuremath{\forestoption{content}}},
    }
  }  
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{forest}
mytree,
[+
  [*
    [2]
    [\pi]
  ]
  [-
    [+
      [x]
      [3]
    ]
    [/,tikz={\node[inner sep=2pt,draw=mygreen,line width=1pt,fit=()(!1)(!ll)] {};}
      [y]
      [+
        [5]
        [1]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{forest}
mytree,
[*
  [*,tikz={\node[inner sep=2pt,draw=myblue,line width=1pt,fit=()(!1)(!l)] {};}
    [a]
    [3]
  ]
  [+
    [3]
    [+
      [y]
      [12]
    ]
  ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{minipage}\par

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{forest}
mytree,
[+
  [*
    [2]
    [\pi]
  ]
  [-
    [+
      [x]
      [3]
    ]
    [*,tikz={\node[inner sep=2pt,draw=myblue,line width=1pt,fit=()(!1)(!l)] {};}
      [a]
      [3]
    ]
  ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{forest}
mytree,
[*
  [/,tikz={\node[inner sep=2pt,draw=mygreen,line width=1pt,fit=()(!1)(!ll)] {};}
    [y]
    [+
      [5]
      [1]
    ]
  ]
  [+
    [3]
    [+
      [y]
      [12]
    ]
  ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You want to use `every fit` not `fit` key. Otherwise you will redefine the meaning of `fit` and it is not what you want.

Also when referring to node `(a)` do not write `($a$)` but just `(a)`. I also removed `(1)` from the second `fit` command.

Here is your corrected code:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,backgrounds,fit,shapes,decorations.pathreplacing}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[level distance=8.5mm,
level 1/.style={sibling distance=25mm},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=17mm},
level 3/.style={sibling distance=12mm},
level 4/.style={sibling distance=7mm},every fit/.style=    {rectangle,draw,inner sep=3.5pt}]

\node {+}
child {node {*}
    child {node{2}}
    child {node{$\pi$}}}
child {node {---}
    child {node {+}
        child {node {$x$}}
        child {node {3}}}
    child {node(/){/}
        child {node (y){y}}
        child {node (+){+}
            child {node (5){5}}
            child {node (1){1}}
}}};

\node [draw=green,fit=(/) (y) (+) (5) (1) ] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\hskip 10pt 
\begin{tikzpicture}
[level distance=11mm,
level 1/.style={sibling distance=25mm},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=17mm},
level 3/.style={sibling distance=12mm}, every fit/.style={rectangle,draw=red,inner sep=3.5pt}]

\node (1){*}
child {node(*){*}
    child {node(a){$a$}}
    child {node(3){3}}}
child {node {+}
    child {node{3}}
    child {node {+}
            child {node {y}}
            child {node {12}}}
};
\node[fit={(a) (3) (*) }]{};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[level distance=11mm,
level 1/.style={sibling distance=25mm},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=17mm},
level 3/.style={sibling distance=12mm},every fit/.style={rectangle,draw,inner sep=3.5pt}]
\node {+}
child {node {*}
    child {node{2}}
    child {node{$\pi$}}}
child {node {---}
    child {node {+}
        child {node {$x$}}
        child {node {3}}}
    child {node(*){*}
        child {node (a){$a$}}
        child {node (3){3}}
}};

\node [draw=red, fit={(*) (a) (3)}] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\hskip 10pt 
\begin{tikzpicture}
[level distance=11mm,
level 1/.style={sibling distance=25mm},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=17mm},
level 3/.style={sibling distance=12mm}, every fit/.style={rectangle,draw,inner sep=3.5pt}]

\node {*}
child {node(/){/}
            child {node (y){y}}
            child {node (+){+}
                child {node (5){5}}
                child {node (1){1}}
}}
child {node {+}
    child {node{3}}
    child {node {+}
            child {node {y}}
            child {node {12}}}
};

\node [fit=(/) (y) (+) (5) (1),draw=green ]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]